# OpenVPN: Only route a specific IP addresses through VPN doesn't work for some websites

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

I wrote

```
route-nopull
route myexternalip.com 255.255.255.255
```

in `.ovpn` config file as it is shown on many tutorials. And for `myexternalip.com` it works well, but for some other sites - does not. For example `analog.com`, `digikey.com`, `speedtest.net`, `whatismyip.com` can access my real ip address, though if I turn on VPN for all connections, it perfoms well. So here is full routing table I've tried to use

```
route-nopull
route myexternalip.com 255.255.255.255
route analog.com 255.255.255.255
route speedtest.net 255.255.255.255
route whatismyip.com 255.255.255.255
```

I suppose, that is because of theese domains having multiple IP adresses, and I have to specify each of them to make it work well, or maybe because of IPv6 adressing, but I don't know how can I fix that. I am doing something wrong, but don't know what exactly.

I am running latest OpenVPN Community (2.5.6) on Windows 10 21H1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routes are never matched against actual domains, only against IP addresses. In your examples, OpenVPN must look up the addresses for the specified domain and add routes *for those addresses*.

Multiple addresses aren't a big deal; if the host "speedtest.net" has four IPv4 addresses (and four IPv6), then OpenVPN could just add four IPv4 routes. (But I'm not sure whether it does. You should check if it actually added those routes!)

The first problem is that domains can have **subdomains.** Now speedtest.com points to one set of IP addresses, but if you visit it you'll be redirected to `www.speedtest.com`, which is a *different* set of IP addresses and no longer matches the generated routes. (The list of IP addresses even changes fairly often, due to the way Fastly CDN works, so those routes might quickly go stale.)

The same happens with whatismyip.com (which redirects to a "www" subdomain, and then pings another subdomain for IPv6 testing), and the same happens with analog.com.

So because OpenVPN must expand domain names to addresses upfront, it can't just do a wildcard match; for something like (hypothetical) `route *.speedtest.net` to work, it would need to get a list of all individual subdomains, look up addresses of *each* subdomain, add routes for all addresses. But because it **cannot** get a list of subdomains (nearly all domain operators block that function), that's pretty much a non-starter.

(And of course, the next problem is that websites are not restricted to accessing only their 'main' domain. As soon as you start a test on [www.speedtest.com](http://www.speedtest.com), the website will directly contact various test servers around the world, and as the browser's DevTools would show, those *aren't* subdomains of `.speedtest.com` at all – they're actually subdomains of `.prod.hosts.ooklaserver.net`.)

You can't make this work reliably with just IP routes (unless you knew precisely what domains the website makes requests to); you'd need something that works at a higher layer, e.g. set up an HTTP proxy on your server and combine it with a "Proxy Auto-Config" script that tells browsers whether each domain should be proxied or not.

(Sometimes a better option might be to *exclude* sites that need to bypass the VPN. For example, if you need to access a specific IP range directly while the VPN is active with a 'default route', adding "route 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 net_gateway" would achieve that.)

Comment: Much thanks, just as I thought. So I've routed the whole cdn through vpn and it is ok now. Not the exact thing I needed, but it works.

Comment: I've tried excluding before, but it behaved the same way.